The prisoners and the switch
After studying for a math exam some months ago, I fell in an uneasy sleep and had the oddest dream.
I dreamt I was part of a company of soldiers captured in enemy territory, imprisoned for weeks.
Finally, one day, we all were brought before the prison warden.
He offered us a chance to earn back our freedom - but at the price of having to pass a deadly test.
He placed a sheet of paper displaying the rules of the test on the table we sat around and gave us
six hours to come up with a solution to save our lives.
The rules of this test were given as follows:
Following this discussion, every prisoner will be led to his own seperate cell.
They will be unable to communicate with each other until the test has been passed.
From then on, every day one prisoner will be picked at random and led into a separate cell
containing nothing but a single, massive two-position switch labeled with ON and OFF whose
initial state is unknown to all the prisoners.
The prisoner may flip this switch to his liking.
Before leaving the room, a prison guard will ask this prisoner the question:
"Has every prisoner been inside the switch room yet?"
Should the prisoner truthfully answer the question with yes, then the test has been passed successfully
and all prisoners will be given freedom.
Should the prisoner truthfully answer the question with no, then they will be led back to their cell
and the test will continue.
Should the prisoner answer untruthfully, the prisoners will have failed the test and will face execution.
Naturally, the table erupted in a heated debate about which strategy could save our lives.
How could we possibly brave this seemingly impossible challenge with just a single bit of information
at our hands? Surely we were doomed. Or were we?
Hours passed, but at very last our commander came up with an ingenious method that would guarantee our survival,
without a shadow of doubt the most brilliant idea I had ever heard in my entire life.
I suddenly awoke, dazed, scrambled to write down the seemingly impossible solution, but alas! - I had already forgotten
most of it. Today I find myself questioning whether this dream was a streak of genius or madness.
My question is: Does this puzzle really have a definitive solution that ensures the soldier's survival?
Or is this merely the stuff of dreams?
I have provided my own attempts at a solution below for inspiration.
Another tip: This problem is basically a harder version of the problem known as '100 prisoners and a lightbulb', the major
difference being that the question will need to be answered correctly every day and not only when a prisoner wishes to give an answer.
This reduces the timeframe of the problem significantly and the solution will need to be found much faster.
Both problems are related to the Coupon collector's problem. Perhaps understanding these problems can provide some insight?

I suspect that there's no solution for $n\geq4$, but I have no proof of this fact. Does anyone know a solution for $n=4$?

There's no solution for 4. On the 4th day, a prisoner who hasn't yet been in needs to know if he's the last one. That means the switch needs to be in some position (let's say ON) if the three other prisoners have all been in, and OFF otherwise. But that means the switch is OFF if we had 1-1-2 or 1-1-1, and the 4th day prisoner can't know which. He has to set the switch, but there's no way he can do so such that the final prisoner would know whether or not he can escape on day 5.

Are the prisoners allowed to remain silent (or answer "I don't know") or do they have to answer with only "yes" or "no"?

@fljx They are not allowed to remain silent or give any other answer then "yes" or "no".

Is it out of the question for prisoners to rot13(or noyr gb npphengryl xrrc genpx bs gur qnlf gung unir cnffrq? Vs abg, ubj npphengr pna gurl or?) It seems like that would be a good way to significantly boost their chances of success.

@BlueHerring For the purpose of this puzzle I assumed that every prisoner has access to some sort of calendar or a notebook for the purpose of timekeeping. They all know the number of passed days with 100% accuracy, I just failed to clarify that.

Obvious 1:

 For n soldiers it is obvious that anyone called up for the switch room for the first n-1 days should always answer the question with 'no' as there is no possible way that every soldier could have entered the switch room yet.

Obvious 2:

 From the given rules it can be derived that the question asked by the guard can only be truthfully be answered with 'yes' by a prisoner that has never entered the switch room before. This is because if someone that had already entered the switch room before were to enter the switch room again, the question would have already been answered by a prisoner before them. Regardless of whether this prisoner entered the switch room before or not, all prisoners must have been in the switch room at this point, and answering the question should have resulted in either freedom or death, neither of which has occurred, revealing our hypothetical situation to be impossible. If the prisoner before them has already entered the switch room before, the same holds true for them, forming a recursive chain all the way down. This also means that any prisoner that has already been inside the switch room can safely always answer the question with 'no' as well.

Strategy A:

 Binary Counter


 This simple strategy does not guarantee survival, but it does increase the chance of survival by a small margin, especially when n is small.


 Firstly, the prisoner that enters the switch room on first day on the experiment will flip the switch in the 'OFF' position if it is not in this position already. (We do not know the initial state of the switch after all.) After that, every prisoner that re-enters the switch room flips the switch. This gives the switch the same purpose as the least important bit of a binary counter - the parity bit. Overflow is lost.


 'OFF' thus means that the switch room has been re-entered an even,  'ON' that the room has been re-entered an odd number of times.


 On the day that all prisoners have been inside the switch room, the following must hold true:
 Number of Prisoners + Number of times the switch room has been re-entered = Current Day


 Then consequently, this must be true as well: Parity(Number of Prisoners) + Parity(Switch) = Parity(Current Day)


 Thus, if the Number of Prisoners (n) is even, then every day where Parity(Switch) =/= Parity(Current Day) the question can be safely answered with 'no' as well. Is the Number of Prisoners uneven, then the question can be safely answered with 'no' on days where Parity(Switch) = Parity(Current Day).
 This is the best I could come up with, but this answer does not yet satisfy me.


I do not follow "obvious 2". If on Day 1 prisoner 1 goes in the room and on Day 2 it's prisoner 1 again, why would the question have been answered by someone before them?

@KateGregory The formulation is not the best, but think what happens when the last person that never visited the room does : either that persone answer True and everyone is free, or they answer false and everyone is dead. That mean that if you already went into the room, you have to answer false. If everyone would have already entered the room, the game would have stopped.

You could refine the probability of success using the Coupon-Collector's distribution and one bit of info to improve on that,

 But there is no definitive solution for $n \ge 4$.


 Consider a prisoner entering the room for the first time on day n. It is possible that everyone else has entered, and thus he must answer "yes," and otherwise he must answer "no." The only indicator he can have is the position of the switch, meaning it must be in one state (let's say ON wlog) if he must answer yes, and OFF otherwise.


 In the case where he sees OFF, it may or may not be that he's the penultimate prisoner to enter. If he is, then on day n+1 the final prisoner may enter who is faced with the same circumstance: The switch must be in one position if he should answer "yes," and the other position otherwise. Our day n prisoner will have an OFF switch whether or not he's the penultimate prisoner, so there is no method by which he can ensure the switch is correctly positioned for day n+1.


 If $n \le 3$, then our hypothetical day n prisoner WILL know for certain that he is the penultimate prisoner, so the above doesn't hold.

While not part of the question:

 For the prisoners to optimize their chance of success, they should just use the switch to count the parity of the number of unique prisoners that have visited the room, and say "yes" as soon as that is the same as the parity of n, and the current day number is a bit less than the mean of the coupon collector's distribution for n. I think it gets pretty complicated to compute the exact optimal point, but hopefully the prisoner have access to a computer and can run a quick simulation to sort that out.


I ran some simulations on the n=100 case, and found that this strategy is surprisingly strong, though my initial guess that it would be a bit above the mean because there's no confusion with prisoner n-1 is overshadowed by the heavy tail. The mean of the distribution would be 518.7, but an on-parity prisoner should declare he's the last one any time after 424 days have passed. If he does so, all the prisoners escape a bit over 60% of the time.

Edit: It actually looks like this solution doesn't actually work, seeing as there's nothing preventing the same prisoner being called multiple times (thanks for pointing that out ConnieMnemonic). I suppose this idea could still be used to get a rough idea of how many unique prisoners have come through the room, but no more than that.

While it's a bit more of a creative / unique answer, I think it would work. So here's my stab at it:
There was one small detail I noticed that gave me a bit of hope for our poor prisoners:

 "From then on, every day one prisoner will be picked at random and led into a separate cell containing nothing but a single, massive two-position switch..."

This means that, to get out alive:

 The prisoners could count the number of days passed.

This would work because:

 In the meeting room beforehand, the prisoners could get a headcount, so they'd know how many prisoners there were in total. After that, it's a simple matter of keeping track of the days. The prisoner called on the n'th day would simply answer "yes," and every other prisoner would answer "no."


 Since the prisoners were given the instructions on a piece of paper, I think it's safe to assume that the details of the game were given to the prisoners were similar to the ones provided to us.


 If this commander is as brilliant as they say he is, I'm sure he would've noticed this small detail after re-reading the prompt. He could come up with a method to count the days that had passed with some bit of accuracy, based on the conditions they are being held captive in (e.g. if the cells had clocks in them, windows, etc), and tell each of the prisoners to keep track of the days passed.

The switch:

 In this method, it may seem like the switch isn't very important, but it's actually quite the opposite.


 Let the number of days passed be d. Assuming the prisoners were locked in conditions where it would be difficult to count the days passed (e.g. no windows in the cell), it may be difficult to keep track with accuracy.


 Thus, the switch could be utilized as a sort of checksum, where the ON position signifies that d is odd, and the OFF signifies an even d.

Of course, the greater the number of switches, the better:

 If, for some reason, the prisoners were provided with multiple switches, that would provide more accuracy to their checksum.


 They could use a binary counter, rather than a single bit. For example, if two switches were provided, they could create the values [1, 2, 3, and 4] (not using 0).

Then, they could

 Say that d should always be divisible by the value of the switches, v. This would allow the prisoners to be able to check their counting, then set the switches for the next prisoner.

This may be out of the original scope of the question, but I think realistically it could work, without the need to leave some sort of other signal in the switch room (e.g. a small scratch on the floor for every previous prisoner).
(Edits are welcome, my explanation is a bit rough)

Sadly, this doesn't work.
The prisoners are called randomly; nothing in the problem as stated implies that a prisoner cannot be called more than once to the room.
As a prisoner can be called more than once, the number of days elapsed will only give rough hints and minima, not a sure answer.

@ConnieMnemonic Ah, I didn't consider that. I've edited my answer to explain why it doesn't work, thanks for pointing out the flaw :)
